# How to delete all items in a container from a cosmos database?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I want to read items from an azure cosmos db and delete all

I had hard time using key words and could not use any looping because I have no idea which list/array to loop

```cs
this.container.ReadItemAsync(*);

this.container.DeleteItemAsync().All();
```

Appreciate any Help!

This is how my container looks
[image: This is how my container looks]

Comment: Take a look at [DeleteDocumentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.deletedocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) and [DeleteDocumentCollectionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.deletedocumentcollectionasync?view=azure-dotnet) methods. If you can't loop through documents maybe you can try to delete a collection (depends on your requirements).

Comment: https://sajeetharan.com/2019/02/04/helper-to-delete-all-documents-in-cosmosdb-collection/

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed isn't valid. That is, you cannot just say "delete all documents" like that. And `ReadItemAsync()` is a direct document-read, based on the document's ID (and partition key).

You would need to *query* for all documents, and then delete them in your loop (calling `DeleteItemAsync()` for each ID you found in your query). You'd have to make this query run cross-partition as well (otherwise you'd end up only deleting a subset of your documents).

You can also drop and re-create your collection (which effectively deletes all content in the collection).

Cosmos DB also has a Bulk Executor library (bulk inserts, bulk updates, bulk deletes). Perhaps this will work for you, and avoids having to delete and re-create your collection (just be aware that, if you have a lot of documents, you may run into throttling issues based on your Request Units).

Comment: Can I use collection for a container ?

Comment: "collection" and "container' are synonymous.